# why is my code adding the quantity of apples to all item quantities in the selected packages and not just one item of the selected packages

Tags: sql, vb.net

why is my code adding the quantity of apples to all item quantities in the selected packages and not just one item of the selected packages

```
 Dim cmd2 As New SqlCommand("UPDATE ALineTable SET Quantity = ALineTable.Quantity + (Select sum(ALineTable.Quantity) FROM BLineTable Where Item Like 'Apple%'", con)
        isFirst = True
        For i As Integer = 0 To chkLstPackage.Items.Count - 1
            If chkLstPackage.GetItemCheckState(i) = CheckState.Checked Then
                If isFirst = True Then
                    cmd2.CommandText += " AND (Package= @Package" + i.ToString
                    isFirst = False
                Else
                    cmd2.CommandText += " OR Package= @Package" + i.ToString
                End If
                cmd2.Parameters.Add("@Package" + i.ToString, SqlDbType.Int).Value = chkLstPackage.Items(i)
            End If

        Next
        cmd2.CommandText += ")) From ALineTable"
```

any help is appreciated!

Table Schema:

BHeaderTable:  Shows the available packages and items they contain

```
| PackageID (PK) | Weight | TotalPrice 
-------------------------------------------------------
| 1                 | 19.5   | $39.00 
-------------------------------------------------------
| 2                 | 31.5   | $52.00      
-------------------------------------------------------
| 3                 |  34    | $60.00
-------------------------------------------------------
```

BLineTable:  (ItemID is PK, PackageID is FK to BHeaderTable, is also a PK in this table as well)

```
ItemID | PackageID | ItemDesc  | Weight| Price  | Quantity|
----------------------------------------------------------
1      | 1         |  orange   | 2.5   | 2.00   |  1
----------------------------------------------------------
2      | 1         |  banana   | 7.0   | 15.00  |  2
----------------------------------------------------------
3      | 1         |  apple    | 3.0   | 7.00   |  1
----------------------------------------------------------
1      | 2         |  orange   | 2.5   | 2.00   |  3
----------------------------------------------------------
2      | 2         |  banana   | 7.0   | 15.00  |  3
----------------------------------------------------------
3      | 2         |  apple    | 3.0   | 7.00   |  1
----------------------------------------------------------
1      | 3         |  orange   | 2.5   | 2.00   |  4
----------------------------------------------------------
2      | 3         |  banana   | 7.0   | 15.00  |  3
----------------------------------------------------------
3      | 3         |  apple    |3.0    | 7.00   |  1
----------------------------------------------------------
```

AHeaderTable (customer picks packageID's 1 and 2 which are selected using a the chklistbox)

```
ReportID (PK) | PackageID (PK,Fk) | Weight | TotalPrice 
-------------------------------------------------------
 1            | 1                 | 19.5   | $39.00 
-------------------------------------------------------
 1            | 2                 | 31.5   | $52.00      
-------------------------------------------------------
```

ALineTable (After the Update query takes place it should look like this, orange is on top of the list and got the attributes of all the apples of the selected packages and got updated into orange)

```
ReportID(PK,FK) | ItemID (PK)  | PackageID (Pk,FK) | ItemDesc     | Weight| Price  | Quantity|
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        |     1       | 1                 |  Orange      | 8.5   | 16.00  |  3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        |     2       | 1                 |  Banana      | 7.0   | 15.00  |  2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        |     1       | 2                 |  Strawberry  | 2.5   | 2.00   |  3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        1        |     2       | 2                 |  Banana      | 7.0   | 15.00  |  3
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: aren't you missing a `WHERE` on this `UPDATE` command? I can only see one that I would assign to the `select`

Comment: possibly, should it be after the " )) From ALineTable" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a where clause:

```
update ALineTable
set Quantity = ALineTable.Quantity + (
  select sum(BLineTable.Quantity)
  from BLineTable
  where Item like 'Apple%'
   and (Package = @Package1 
     or Package = @Package2 -- ...
   )
/* missing where: */ 
where ALineTable.SomeColumn= @SomeValue
```

Comment: could you elaborate on this code? I don't understand what you're saying here, such as what do I need to put after the Where clause

Comment: I'd say you should put the first package you want to update as the where clause.

Comment: Sorry, took me a couple reads to see where the package stuff went. I thought it was related to the lines you were updating instead of the part of the subquery for updating the quantity.

Comment: Yeah I can see how that got confusing

Comment: for the last WHERE clause on the bottom, could I say Where ALineTable.Item = (Select Top 1 Item From ALineTable)

Comment: For that last where clause would this work to take the first item of the combined selected packages and only update it's attributes? like 'where ALineTable.Item = (Select TOP 1 Item from AlineTable Where (package = (AT SYMBOL)package or package = (AT SYMBOL)package1 or package = (AT SYMBOL)package2 -- ...)' or would I be able to just leave out specifiying packages and it will already be picking the top item inside the selected packages and just have my code look like ''where ALineTable.Item = (Select TOP 1 Item from AlineTable) '

Comment: @ncarpenter can you include your table schema? that would probably help this make sense.

Comment: @NCarpenter Here is an example using `update top (1)` with guesses at your table schema: http://rextester.com/DAIY13991

Comment: I posted the table schema and some details as to what is going on. As you'll notice, I am taking out apples but putting the attributes of apples (weight, price, quantity) into the first orange on the table.

Comment: @NCarpenter Okay, I'll review it when I get back in about two hours, but this rextester demo might help: http://rextester.com/DAIY13991

Comment: @NCarpenter Sorry, even with the edit still doesn't really make sense to me what you are doing. e.g. why does the weight and price change for the first row, and why are you adding apples quantity to oranges?

Comment: @SqlZim I actually figured it out how to do what I needed. It's just a weird requirement I have to do, I was using sample data instead of the data from work since obviously that can't be shared. I had to exclude a specific item ( I was using apples in this sample) from a report (basically they didn't want to see the word 'Apple' come up on the report) but its quantity still had to be accounted for because a shipment report needs to know how many boxes there actually will be shipped

Comment: and I did this by adding the missing quantity of the excluded item onto an item that was going in the shipment order that was allowed to come up on the report.. It was ridiculous I appreciate your time and help though